# One or more instances could not be made persistent

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have been struggling to persistent my classes using JDO. I have followed documentation but I am always getting the same error msg.

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: One or more instances could not be made persistent
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistentAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:791)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistentAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:765)
    at com.db.JDO.createEntry(JDO.java:28)
    at com.kb.JDODataPopulation.buildData(JDODataPopulation.java:103)
    at com.kb.JDODataPopulation.<init>(JDODataPopulation.java:12)
    at com.kb.EntProgGoogleAppServlet.doGet(EntProgGoogleAppServlet.java:14)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
The class "com.film.Film" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "com.film.Film" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.assertClassPersistable(ObjectManagerImpl.java:5464)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1802)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1745)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjects(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1685)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistentAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:780)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistentAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:765)
    at com.db.JDO.createEntry(JDO.java:28)
    at com.kb.JDODataPopulation.buildData(JDODataPopulation.java:103)
    at com.kb.JDODataPopulation.<init>(JDODataPopulation.java:12)
    at com.kb.EntProgGoogleAppServlet.doGet(EntProgGoogleAppServlet.java:14)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong but this is the stack trace I am getting every time my application tries to push data into DataStore.

My Classes:

```
    @PersistenceCapable
    public class Film {

        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        Key key;
        @Persistent
        private String filmName = null;
        @Persistent
        private Date filmProductionDate = new Date();
        @Persistent
        @Embedded
        private Genres filmGenres = null;
        @Persistent
        @Embedded
        private Director filmDirector = null;
        @Persistent
        @Embedded
        private ArrayList<Stars> filmStars = new ArrayList<Stars>();
        @Persistent
        @Embedded
        private Metascore filmMetascore = null;
        @Persistent
        @Embedded   
        private Duration filmDuration = null;
}
    @PersistenceCapable
    @EmbeddedOnly
    public class Director {

        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        Key key;
        @Persistent
        private String directorSurname = null;
        @Persistent
        private String directorForname = null;
}
@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class Duration {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Key key;
    @Persistent
    private Integer duration = 0;
}

@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class Genres {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Key key;
    @Persistent
    private String[] genres = null;
}

@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class Metascore {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Key key;
    @Persistent
    private Integer metascoreValue = 0;
}
@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class Stars {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Key key;
    @Persistent
    private String starSurname = null;
    @Persistent
    private String starForname = null;
}
```

The Code I am trying to run

```
public class JDO {
    private static PersistenceManager PM;

    private void createPersistanceManager() {
        try {
            PM = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public <T> void createEntry(Object obj) {
        createPersistanceManager();
        try {
            PM.makePersistentAll(obj);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            PM.close();
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do here is to create generic JDO controller that can accept any Object(classes) and preforms algorithms on them by calling functions.

Comment: The error message is clear `The class "com.film.Film" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.`

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I am unsure how to fix it

Comment: errm, enhance the classes perhaps?

Comment: Google app engine should enhance classes when complied

Comment: if it is configured to ...

Comment: I think my problem was with project structure. The problem was with eclipse oxygen and new google app engine plugin becuase 
something was not where it should be. 
Reverting back to neon, older version of the plugin and creating new project solved the problem